# What personal food can cross land border from Canada to the USA?

Tags: usa, canada, food-and-drink, borders, land-borders

I am crossing the border from Canada into USA with a cooler full of personal food.

After reading [this](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/82/~/travelers-bringing-food-into-the-u.s.-for-personal-use) document, I am not fully clear about the restrictions.

I am bringing some processed pepperoni, that I think only contains pork. I am bringing unlabeled fruit, as well as cooked hard boiled eggs. The other contents of my cooler are explicitly allowed.

Will I have any trouble crossing the border? I really hate border stops setting my timelines back.

Comment: Have you ever been stopped before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Processed pepperoni

This is a bit unclear, one paragraph says they're prohibited and another says canned and unopened pork products are ok. I think you should be careful with this one and leave the pepperoni unopened.

> Fresh (chilled or frozen), dried, cured, and fully cooked meat is
>   generally prohibited from most countries. [...] Pork should be
>   commercially canned and labeled in unopened containers

#### Unlabelled fruit

They'll need to inspect them even if they were labelled, and unless you can prove they were grown in Canada, they will most probably be confiscated.

> Fruits and vegetables grown in Canada are generally admissible, if
>   they have labels identifying them as products of Canada. Fruits and
>   vegetables merely purchased in Canada are not necessarily admissible

For fruits grown elsewhere in the Americas, you can check the [FAVIR](https://epermits.aphis.usda.gov/manual/index.cfm?CFID=3741758&CFTOKEN=f491f3953f3220a5-F741C591-E75E-5035-6E692B82A3446499&ACTION=pubHome) database. You'll notice there's no US in the dropdown, I would be careful with US imported produce, I've seen Florida oranges confiscated at the border but then again they might let them in.
As for packaged fruits as opposed to raw ones, once more it depends where it was processed. [This](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/import_export/plants/manuals/ports/downloads/miscellaneous.pdf) guideline (table 3.123) has all the information.

#### Hard boiled eggs

Those should be ok as Exotic Newcastle Disease seems to be [under control](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/animals/terrestrial-animals/diseases/reportable/nd/fact-sheet/eng/1330202454619/1330202602677) in Canada and few [cases](http://www.inspection.gc.ca/animals/terrestrial-animals/diseases/reportable/2016/avian-influenza-2015-/eng/1425829816854/1425829817713) of HPAI were reported.

> Eggs and egg products from Exotic Newcastle Disease (END) and Highly
>   Pathogenic Avian Influenza (HPAI) affected regions, including cooked
>   eggs, if not accompanied by a USDA Veterinary Service import permit
>   remain prohibited regardless if those items are for personal
>   consumption.

Comment: Last time I drove into Canada, the person ahead of me had a large quantity of apples, which were specifically prohibited. (Medfly issues in California.) I think he must have tried to hide them in his trunk and lie, because they led him away.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus of course they would, you're supposed to declare everything even allowed items. The question is about driving into the US though, Canadian rules are probably different

Comment: What about fruit an vegetables grown in US or other countries in the Americas? Most Canadian fruit comes from the same places the US fruit comes from.

Comment: @ScottF I updated the answer with more detail

Comment: Is there a difference between raw fruit, and packaged fruit cups

Comment: @ScottF yes, it depends where it was processed. Check [this](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/import_export/plants/manuals/ports/downloads/miscellaneous.pdf) guideline, go to table 3.123 (roughly page 160)